# Module not found: Compiler error when using @Input Property - Angular 6

Tags: angular

Have generated parent and child components (at same folder level) - using ng generate component...

Am getting following compiler error:

./src/app/parent/parent.component.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './<app-child [childMessage]="parentMessage"></app-child>' in 'c:\myapp\src\app\parent'

child.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() childMessage: string;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

parent.component.ts:
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: '<app-child [childMessage]="parentMessage"></app-child>',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  parentMessage = "hello from parent";
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ParentComponent } from './parent/parent.component';
import { ChildComponent } from './child/child.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ParentComponent,
    ChildComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Replace `templateUrl` with `template` in `parent.component.ts`

Answer (score 1):

Just replace templateurl with template, since you are directly using Html

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `<app-child [childMessage]="parentMessage"></app-child>`,
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  parentMessage = "hello from parent";
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `templateUrl` to `template`

> parent.component.ts

```
@Component({ 
    selector: 'app-parent', 
    template: `<app-child [childMessage]="parentMessage"></app-child>`, 
    styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css'] }) 
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit { 
    parentMessage = "hello from parent";
     constructor() { } 
     ngOnInit() { }
 }
```